Is a double underscore illegal in VHDL?
I'm learning VHDL and see some people use double underscores, i.e., __, as the component identifier, or assigned signal of a port in case of identical port names. However, this is shown as illegal in Vivado.
Is it really illegal to use double underscores or can they be legally used with some configuration?

Hello ... could you point us at somewhere where people are using double-underscores?  I'm curious to follow up on that.

The syntax doesn't allow adjacent underlines, clearly prohibited by the syntax definition in BNF.  Also it doesn't permit leading or trailing underlines.
From IEEE Standard VHDL Language Reference Manual IEEE Std 1076 (2019 Edition):

Section 15.4.2 Basic identifiers
A basic identifier consists only of letters, digits, and underlines.
basic_identifier ::= letter { [ underline ] letter_or_digit }
letter_or_digit ::=  letter | digit
letter ::=           upper_case_letter | lower_case_letter


This syntax is identical in the 2000, 2008 and 2019 versions of the standard.
Basic Identifiers are case insensitive
Note that "letter" includes those with various accents, as the character set is ISO 8859-1.
An extended identifier (section 15.4.3) with adjacent or leading or trailing underlines would be allowed, as they are simple non-empty sequences of graphic character: \__doubles__\

Given the ubiquity of C-type identifier syntax (where identifiers are an alpha_under followed by zero-or-more alpha_under_digit), it wouldn't be surprising if some VHDL systems were more liberal by design or by accident, but I wouldn't rely on it.
For contrast, a Verilog simple identifier is an alpha_under followed by a zero-or-more alpha_under_digit_dollar; case-sensitive, which is "C-like with dollar signs".

There's also 13.8 Comments and 13.6 String literals. Other lexical elements only allow a single underscore. There are no semantic constructs that contain underscores other than found in lexical elements. It's a special character and  not a separator or delimiter.  Non-standard compliant tools when relied on can have portability issues, e.g.13.2 Lexical elements, separators, and delimiters  "... At least one separator is required between an identifier or an abstract literal and an adjacent identifier or abstract literal." as in 13ns comprise of an abstract literal followed by an identifier.

I modified a code example on the EDA Playground site, changing an entity name from or_gate to or__gate everywhere, and every simulator on that site generates either error or warning messages.  Some messages explicitly mention the double underscore being a problem.
This is a strong indication that using double underscores is not portable and should be avoided.
Looking at IEEE Std 1076-2008, section 15.4.2 Basic identifiers, it shows that a single underline between letters and digits is allowed, but it does not explicitly show multiple adjacent underlines.
